# How can stop JpaItemWriter if transaction failed in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I use Spring Batch to insert datas into database. When something is wrong in datas that I wanted to insert (and so, no datas is inserted), I would like writer stop the whole job.

This is my job:

```
<step id="recopyTotoStep">
    <tasklet>
         <chunk reader="totoReader"
                processor="totoProcessor"
                writer="totoWriter"
                commit-interval="5000" />
    </tasklet>
    <next on="*" to="anotherStep" />
    <end on="???" />
</step>
```

This is my bean:

```
  <bean id="totoWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
  </bean>
```

And here is an exception exemple I can have:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same
>   entity
>   [some_entity...]
>   are being merged. Managed:
>   [other_entity...]; Detached:
>   [some_entity...]

I know I can add a step "decision" (where I'll add some controls) and it will resolve my problem, but I would like to be sure it's not possible to do like I explained.

Comment: isn't your job already stopping if writer throws an error? I mean to say, you are not skipping any exceptions so job should stop.

Comment: The job continues the treatment and so "anotherStep" is called and played.

Comment: yes, that is the normal behavior , step -1 will be marked as failed and job will continue to execute next steps. you need to do conditional start of second step as specified in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did that and it works like I want.

```
<step id="recopyTotoStep">
        <tasklet>
             <chunk reader="totoReader"
                    processor="totoProcessor"
                    writer="totoWriter"
                    commit-interval="5000" />
        </tasklet>
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="anotherStep" />
        <end on="*" />
    </step>
```